# TypeError: invalid path: UnparsedPath, Geopandas, Python

Tags: python, typeerror, geopandas

I am trying to read a shapefile data using geopandas in python, but it produces the following error:

```
import geopandas as gp
fl="M:/rathore/vic_5km/L2_data/L2_data/DAMSELFISH_distributions.shp"
data=gp.read_file(fl)
TypeError: invalid path: UnparsedPath(path='M:/rathore/vic_5km/L2_data/L2_data/DAMSELFISH_distributions.shp')
```

`gp.read_file()` is the command to read the file in geopandas

Comment: have you already tried it with the absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look at the [source code here](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/blob/master/fiona/path.py), and windows paths are said to be confusing for the parser, because they look like URL schemes (because of the "x:/" pattern).

There is a workarpound, but it will not recognize your path to be a windows one if you use slashes like this. Try to replace your path with:

```
fl=r"M:\rathore\vic_5km\L2_data\L2_data\DAMSELFISH_distributions.shp"
```

Or even better: use the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module and the `resolve()` method to normalize the path...

Comment: What happens if you use `pathlib` and use the [is_file()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_file) method?

Comment: `Path('M:\\rathore\\vic_5km\\L2_data\\L2_data\\DAMSELFISH_distributions.shp').resolve()` gives- `WindowsPath('M:/rathore/vic_5km/L2_data/L2_data/DAMSELFISH_distributions.shp')` as out put. and `is_file()` gives True

Comment: And if you pass that `Path` bject to geopandas instead of the former string?

Comment: It shows error that `expected string or buffer`, when I pass the `Path` object